# routerLink to route with parameters not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `routerLink` on my page that goes to a certain route but Im getting this error

Basically I have an asset page that has a unique id then when you click the button the id changes and the route should update so asset/sa3384320402 should then change to asset/i44309509439 the new id

[image]

my routerLink is as follows

```
<button [routerLink]="['/asset', newId]">click</button>
```

my routing page

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '',
            children: [
                { path: 'week-1', component: Week1Component },
                { path: 'week-1/asset/:id', component: AssetPageComponent }
            ]
        }
    ])
],
```

and my asset-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';
import { ContentfulService } from '../../../contentful.service';

import * as _ from 'lodash';

declare var Player: any;
declare var Vimeo: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-page',
  templateUrl: './asset-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-page.component.scss']
})
export class AssetPageComponent implements OnInit {
  asset: Entry<any>[];
  id: string;
  videoID: string;

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id')))
    .subscribe((asset) => {
      this.asset = asset;
      console.log(this.asset);
    });
   }
}
```

Im not sure what Is going on because if I go to that route it does work just not through the routerLink?

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have tried the following with these results

`<button [routerLink]="['/week-1/asset', newId]">click</button>` - same error as above

`<button [routerLink]="['asset/', newId]">click</button>` - just adds the new route to the end of the old route

`<button [routerLink]="['asset', newId]">click</button>` - just adds the new route to the end of the old route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are trying to access is "/asset/:id", but your route is defined as "/week-1/asset/:id". So you either need to provide the full path to the router link, like this:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/week-1/asset', newId]">click</button>
```

or assuming you are already at the week-1 route, you can provide a relative path by omitting the first forward slash:

```
<button [routerLink]="['asset', newId]">click</button>
```

Comment: if i do `<button [routerLink]="['/week-1/asset', newId]">click</button>`  I get the same error as posted above `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'week-1/asset/3SrqtB4haMCI8AsoEM84w4'` and if I dont have the forward slash in front of asset It just adds the new route to the end of the old one

Comment: The forward slash at the beginning defines an absolute route, so when you leave it off the route should be appended to your current route by design. What route is your button on?

Comment: so the button is on the asset page so /asset/a32f0f0sdfew9es right but what I want to do is on this button click is change the id on the asset page, please see updated question I dont think I was being specific enough

Comment: This wasnt exactly what needed to happen to make it work but it did point me in the right direction to fix it thanks

Comment: What the problem was in the end? I was completely stumped as to why the above didn't work so would be really interested in finding out what worked.

Comment: I have 3 different routing modules so when I was doing /asset I didnt actually have an /asset it was really app/main/week-1/asset

Answer (score 0):

Try with this button:

```
<button [routerLink]="['asset/', newId]">click</button>
```

Comment: all that does is add that to the end of the current route `week-1/asset/jiWG0Ufzlm4ccUsuYsuWQ` turns into `week-1/asset/jiWG0Ufzlm4ccUsuYsuWQ/week-1/asset/jiWG0Ufzlm4ccUsuYsuWQ` same with asset

Comment: Try with `asset/`

Comment: once again it only adds the new route on to the end of the current route

Comment: Try swapping places of those 2 routes inside of your `routing page` file?

Comment: Last thing that came to my mind is try changing the `week-1/asset/:id` inside of your `routing page` file to `asset/:id` and tell us did it do the trick?

Comment: please see updated question I dont think I was specific enough before